# Imagemagick perspective and virtual pixels

Tags: image-manipulation, imagemagick

I'm trying to automatically straighten an image so that a grid is aligned with the picture.

However, whenever I do the manipulation there is a white border around the image.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: What do you want the extra space to be filled with? Do you want it cropped?

Comment: Also, what ImageMagick command are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, turns out I had some values the wrong way round, which forced virtual pixels to be made.